# Spark sql is working, but it seems that without any cluster manager, it is possible?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a hadoop cluster with 4 nodes(1master, 3slaves). And I create some hive tables from files stored in hdfs. Then I configure mysql as the hive metastore and copy the hive-site.xml file inside conf folder of spark.

To install spark, I just download and extract spark in the master node. And after copy the hive-site.xml inside spark conf folder, I start spark with `spark-shell command`. Its needed to install in slave nodes also?

Im asking this because, Im executing with success spark sql queries like below, but if I try to acess the cluster manager default page in localhost:8080, it shows "Unable to connect". So it seems that spark sql is working fine, but without any cluster manager working, this is possible??

```
var hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
query = hiveContext.sql("select * from customers");
query.show()
```

master:8080

[image]

Comment: what is the exact command `spark-shell`that you have started? have you set the master with this command?

Comment: I just download and extract the spark on the namenode. I oopy the hive-site.xml file into spark "conf" folder and did not any other configuration. To start spark, I just execute this command "spark-shell".

Comment: Please see my answer below.. I explained how to start spark with hadoop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First , you have to let spark knows where your Hadoop configurations are, by setting the env variable `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` in your spark-env.sh file

Then, when starting the `spark-shell`  you have to tell spark to use  yarn as the master:
`spark-shell --master yarn-client`

for more information you could see the [spark with yarn docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html)

Comment: Thanks, I thought that it was only necessary start spark with spark-shell and spark uses its own cluster manager. But now Im trying your solution, but after enter the env variable in spark-env.sh file and start spark as you said, Im having this message always appearing and spark dont starts: "INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_15... (state: ACCEPTED). Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: It's not an error.. But it is a status of your job spark in yarn meaning that the job is accepted by yarn and it will assign some resources to the spark job (spark-shell)

Comment: But how I can start spark now to execute some queries? That message is also appearing and dont stops to show.

Comment: You should see yarn resource manager... It might  not have enough resources to assign to spark.. In the Web ui of resource manager you could see if the application master has been assigned or not

Comment: Do you have your hadoop processes all started well?

Comment: Yes, all processes started, when I write jps all processes appear.

Comment: As it appears on the image you put in the question ulyou have no ressources available. There is no node managers running (which are the real workers)... You have to start nodemanagers on all the other nodes (3 nodes in your case)

Comment: Strange, I have 3 nodes, 1 master and 2 slaves. When I start the hadoop cluster I did jps in the slaves and it appeard Datanode and NodeManager in each slave. But now that Im trying to put spark working with yarn, I execute now jps in slave nodes and it appear just: Datanode and Worker, no nodemanager. It was supposed to dont appear NodeManager and appaer worker instead? Or should appear both?

Comment: In the masternode appears the ResourceManager, Master, SparkSubmit, RunJar, SecondaryNamenode processes. In slave nodes appears: Datanode and Worker.

Comment: That means you have to start node managers on all slave nodes... Cause they are not started..and without them you have no compute resources on your cluster

Comment: Thanks for your help. But its not working again, I start again the node managers with ./start-yarn.sh now they are running, and when I start spark with yarn with spark-shell --master yarn-client I get the same page without resources as you said and FinalStatus as undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111476/discussion-between-user1314742-and-codin).

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to start the cluster separately; by default spark-shell runs locally.
2. You'll need to have spark binaries on the worker nodes as well.

For documentation on starting your own spark cluster, see here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didnt know that, but can you explain more clearly your first point? I need to start spark with "spark-shell" but also start the cluster with other command?

Comment: IMHO, I do not think it answer this question.. The question is about spark on hadoop cluster..  not spark standalone mode